# Rails forum engine Forem error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I was able to install the rails forum engine Forem:

> https://github.com/radar/forem/blob/master/README.md

I am also using Devise for authentication. When I went to access it at `http:/localhost:3000/forums`, I got this error message.

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does indeed seem to because you're missing the `main_app` before the links. Your `new_user_session_path` should be `main_app.new_user_session_path`.

This is because the partial is being used by the engine (by way of the application layout), and so it doesn't see `new_user_session_path` helper within the context of the *engine*, because it's only available in the application.

So yeah, just put `main_app.` before those routes and it should fix it.

Comment: Ryan, if I'm NOT signed in, I can access http:localhost:3000/forums/ with main_app in front of the routes. But if I try to sign in, and go to localhost:3000/forums, I get the can_read_forem_forums? method error, so still broken

Comment: @Michael: This error is fixed now. It was this one: https://github.com/radar/forem/issues/88. I've left it open because I am not happy with the solution. I may end up changing `user_class` to take a string rather than a class, as I think that is what is causing that problem.